# How to Convert CSV to Raster in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, raster, rasterizing

I have a CSV (value, carbon, latitude, longitude) that I am trying to create a raster  from.

CSV file sample:

```
Carbon Latitude Longitude coords.x1 coords.x2
1      385       36        74        36        74
2      463       36        74        36        74
3       35       36        74        36        74
4       38       36        74        36        74
5       34       36        74        36        74
6       11       36        74        36        74
7       46       36        74        36        74
8       18       36        74        36        74
9      213       36        74        36        74
10     619       36        74        36        74
11     140       36        74        36        74
12      40       36        74        36        74
13      42       36        74        36        74
14      18       36        74        36        74
15     277       36        74        36        74
16     641       36        74        36        74
17     416       36        74        36        74
18     459       36        74        36        74
19    1073       36        74        36        74
20     628       36        74        36        74
21     425       36        74        36        74
22     550       36        74        36        74
23     163       36        74        36        74
24     366       36        74        36        74
25     379       36        74        36        74
26     279       36        74        36        74
27     284       36        74        36        74
28     454       36        74        36        74
29     813       36        74        36        74
30    1296       36        74        36        74
31    1539       36        74        36        74
32     997       36        74        36        74
33     498       36        74        36        74
34     857       36        74        36        74
35     413       36        74        36        74
36      76       36        74        36        74
37     189       36        74        36        74
38     130       36        74        36        74
39      22       36        74        36        74
40      18       36        74        36        74
41     137       36        74        36        74
42     521       36        74        36        74
43      28       36        74        36        74
44     188       36        74        36        74
45     101       36        74        36        74
46      19       36        74        36        74
47     935       36        74        36        74
48      22       36        74        36        74
49      22       36        74        36        74
50     165       36        74        36        74
51     274       36        74        36        74
52     316       36        74        36        74
53     270       36        74        36        74
54     125       36        74        36        74
55     116       36        74        36        74
56     109       36        74        36        74
57      70       36        74        36        74
58     194       36        74        36        74
59      36       36        74        36        74
60      24       36        74        36        74
61      93       36        74        36        74
62      32       36        74        36        74
63     144       36        74        36        74
64      47       36        74        36        74
65     304       36        74        36        74
66     338       36        74        36        74
67     214       36        74        36        74
68     150       36        74        36        74
69    1799       36        74        36        74
70     394       36        74        36        74
71      24       36        74        36        74
72     117       36        74        36        74
73     140       36        74        36        74
74      47       36        74        36        74
75       3       36        74        36        74
76     221       36        74        36        74
77      41       36        74        36        74
78     319       36        74        36        74
79     119       36        74        36        74
80      39       36        74        36        74
81       3       36        74        36        74
82       2       36        74        36        74
83      15       36        74        36        74
84      69       36        74        36        74
85      40       36        74        36        74
86     233       36        74        36        74
87      15       36        74        36        74
88     147       36        74        36        74
89      50       36        74        36        74
90     348       36        74        36        74
91     549       36        74        36        74
92       5       36        74        36        74
93     191       36        74        36        74
94     409       36        75        36        75
95      93       36        75        36        75
96    1641       36        75        36        75
97     154       36        75        36        75
98     852       36        75        36        75
99    1571       36        75        36        75
100   1173       36        75        36        75
101     19       36        75        36        75
102      9       36        75        36        75
103     15       36        75        36        75
104     67       36        75        36        75
105    666       36        75        36        75
106      3       36        75        36        75
107    227       36        75        36        75
108    130       36        75        36        75
109    423       36        75        36        75
110     31       36        75        36        75
111    559       36        75        36        75
112    143       36        75        36        75
113     63       36        75        36        75
114   1211       36        75        36        75
115    280       36        75        36        75
116   1027       36        75        36        75
117    636       36        75        36        75
118    207       36        75        36        75
119    233       36        75        36        75
120    332       36        75        36        75
121    266       36        75        36        75
122    266       36        75        36        75
123    284       36        75        36        75
124    240       36        75        36        75
125    613       36        75        36        75
126     28       36        75        36        75
127    762       36        75        36        75
128     58       36        75        36        75
129    310       36        75        36        75
130     12       36        75        36        75
131     15       36        75        36        75
132    343       36        75        36        75
133    128       36        75        36        75
134    177       36        75        36        75
135    320       36        75        36        75
136    205       36        75        36        75
137    108       36        75        36        75
138   1445       36        75        36        75
139    109       36        75        36        75
140    251       36        75        36        75
141    262       36        75        36        75
142    282       36        75        36        75
143    188       36        75        36        75
144    207       36        75        36        75
145     63       36        75        36        75
146     63       36        75        36        75
147    194       36        75        36        75
148    170       36        75        36        75
149    196       36        75        36        75
150     85       36        75        36        75
151     93       36        75        36        75
152     79       36        75        36        75
153    656       36        75        36        75
154     56       36        75        36        75
155     93       36        75        36        75
156     28       36        75        36        75
157      4       35        75        35        75
158      3       35        75        35        75
159     82       35        75        35        75
160     48       35        75        35        75
161     64       35        75        35        75
162     72       35        75        35        75
163     86       35        75        35        75
164     12       35        75        35        75
165     73       35        75        35        75
166     77       35        75        35        75
167   2162       35        75        35        75
168    854       35        75        35        75
169     51       35        75        35        75
170     61       35        75        35        75
171     11       35        75        35        75
172      8       35        75        35        75
173     16       35        75        35        75
174     58       35        75        35        75
175     50       35        75        35        75
176     53       35        75        35        75
177      8       35        75        35        75
178     48       35        75        35        75
179    235       35        75        35        75
180     38       35        75        35        75
181     75       35        75        35        75
182     25       35        75        35        75
183     12       35        75        35        75
184     18       35        75        35        75
185     51       35        75        35        75
186     19       35        75        35        75
187     22       35        75        35        75
188   1595       35        75        35        75
189     77       35        75        35        75
190   1673       35        75        35        75
191     42       35        75        35        75
192    120       35        75        35        75
193     66       35        75        35        75
194     53       35        75        35        75
195     66       35        75        35        75
196      6       35        75        35        75
197      5       35        75        35        75
198     36       35        75        35        75
199     54       35        75        35        75
200     46       35        75        35        75

class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 13135 
extent      : 35, 37, 73, 76  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA 
variables   : 3
names       : Carbon, Latitude, Longitude 
min values  :      1,       35,        73 
max values  :   5829,       37,        76
```

**R Script:**

```r
library(sp)  # vector data
library(raster)  # raster data
library(rgdal)  # input/output, projections
library(rgeos)  # geometry ops
library(spdep)  # spatial dependence

foresta<-carbonstock
head(carbonstock)

data<-data.frame(carbonstock$Longitude,carbonstock$Latitude,carbonstock$Carbon)
data<-data.frame(carbonstock)

# points from scratch

coords = cbind(carbonstock$Latitude, carbonstock$Longitude)
sp = SpatialPoints(coords)

# make spatial data frame

spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data)
spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp, data)

# promote data frame to spatial

coordinates(data) = cbind(carbonstock$Latitude, carbonstock$Longitude)
coordinates(data) = ~lon + lat

# back to data

as.data.frame(data)
plot(data,)

library(raster)

dfr <- rasterFromXYZ(data)  #Convert first two columns as lon-lat and third as value               
plot(dfr)
dfr     

library(raster)

# create spatial points data frame

spg <- data
x<-carbonstock$Latitude
y<-carbonstock$Longitude
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y

# coerce to SpatialPixelsDataFrame

gridded(spg) <- TRUE

# coerce to raster

rasterDF <- raster(spg)
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: > coordinates(data) = ~lon + lat
Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ~lon + lat) : 
  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set